# comparing Laplacian and gradient of function on boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider $ E(x)$ some smooth function on $ \Omega$ (some smooth bounded domain in $ R^N$) and suppose $E=0$ on $ \partial \Omega$.

Suppose one knows that there is some $C_1,C_2 \in R$ such that 
$ x \mapsto C_1 | \nabla E(x)|^2 + C_2 \Delta E(x)$ is constant on $ \partial \Omega$.     I am interested in what one can conclude about $\Omega$ and (or) $E$.

Suppose $ \Omega$ is a ball centered at the origin and $E$ is radial.  Then is satisfies the above.     (of course one can take a ball and extend in one more direction and let $E$ be independent of this extra dimension and still arrive at the same thing).     Is this the only option?

Comment: Probably one can get the boundary Laplacian of $E$ if one knows the mean curvature of $\partial\Omega$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any smooth $\Omega$ and $E$ one can perturb $E$ so that the desired conditions hold. Indeed, let $d$ be a global smooth function agreeing with the distance from $\partial\Omega$ in a neighborhood of the boundary. Let $F$ be any smooth function on the boundary, globally extended so that near the boundary it is constant on normal lines. Finally, consider $G = F(x)d^2(x)/2$. Then $G = |\nabla G| = 0$ on the boundary. Tangential to the boundary, $G$ separates at most quartically from zero so its tangential Laplace is zero, so on the boundary $\Delta G = F$. Choosing $F$ appropriately one sees that $E + G$ satisfies the desired conditions.

Comment: @Fan Zheng,  yes I played around with writing the Laplacian on boundary involving the curvature of the boundary but wasn't able to get anything useful.

Comment: @ Connor Mooney.  Thank you very much for the answer.   Let me adjust the questions slightly (and maybe your answer answers this too... i too dumb to tell).   Let $ 0<E$ is smooth and lets assume $E=0$ on the boundary of $ \Omega$.  I am curious if one can have a situation like  $ C_1 | \nabla E(x)|^2 + C_2 \Delta E(x)$ constant on every level set of $E$ (there the $C_i$ can depend on which level set but no more).  thanks

Comment: @Math604: For any $\Omega$, the solution to the eigenvalue problem $\Delta E = -\lambda E$, $E|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$ where $\lambda$ is the smallest eigenvalue would satisfy these conditions with $C_1 = 0$. More generally, for your second question, $E$ would have to solve a PDE of the form $\Delta E + f(E)|\nabla E|^2 = g(E)$.

Comment: @ Connor Mooney,  Thanks for the answer.  I will think more about it.